# How can I put variables inside fopen?

Tags: php

I'm trying to save an image inside a folder. To get this folder I need to pass three directories: Images, id from the user, id from the gallery and the generated name for the image.

```
$directory = "../images/" . $id . "/" . $row[0] . "/" . $new_url;
```

I would like to pass the directory variable to the fopen, I tried this way but is not working.

```
$file = fopen($directory, 'wb');
```

Full code:

```
function uploadimg_func($base, $id){


    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

    $selectgallery = db_queries("SELECT id FROM `galleries` WHERE name = 'Fotos de perfil' AND user_id =  '".$id."' ");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectgallery);

    $new_url = rand(0, pow(10, 5)) . '_' . time() . '.' . "jpg";

    $directory = "../images/" . $id . "/" . $row[0] . "/" . $new_url;

    $file = fopen($directory, 'wb');

    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);

    $createphoto = db_queries("INSERT INTO photos (`name`, `title`, `description`, `gallery_id`,`created_at`) 
    VALUES ('".$new_url."', '', '', '".$row[0]."', now())");

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it giving you an error?

Comment: I am not receiving any error.

Comment: do the directories you reference by $id and $row[0] already exist ? fopen creates files, but not directories that are missing. And just to be clear: you try to create a *file* with a name that is stored in $new_url ? Then your variable name is misleading

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: row[0] is the id from the gallery that already exists. When I try to check the folder the Image doesn't appear.

Comment: did you force error handling with error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$file = fopen($directory, 'wb');
```

Do:

```
$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory, 'wb');
```

Also, make sure that you have the correct folder and file permissions setup.  The images path should be 0775.  If something still goes wrong, check if the folders containing the image files exist....

It's working on my machine perfectly fine.